# Fix running balances for dates when both purchase AND sale transactions occur (multiple criteria)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an imported table from Excel via PQ 'fTrans' that contains the columns 'Ticker', 'Date', 'Shares' and 'Transaction'.

Then I created the following measure:

```
Shares Balance = 
CALCULATE( 
    SUM( fTrans[Shares] ), 
    ALLEXCEPT( fTrans, fTrans[Ticker] ), 
    fTrans[Transaction] = "Purchase", 
    fTrans[Date] <= MAX( fTrans[Date] )
) - 
CALCULATE( 
    SUM( fTrans[Shares] ), 
    ALLEXCEPT( fTrans, fTrans[Ticker] ), 
    fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale", 
    fTrans[Date] <= MAX( fTrans[Date] )
)
```

Which I pasted as an additional column to the following table visual:

| Ticker | Date | Shares | Transaction | Shares Balance |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASAI3 | 03/Mar/2023 | 57 | Purchase | 57 |  |
| ASAI3 | 08/May/2023 | 92 | Purchase | 149 |  |
| ASAI3 | 09/Jun/2023 | 149 | Sale | 0 |  |
| ASAI3 | 19/Jul/2023 | 81 | Purchase | 81 |  |
| ASAI3 | 16/Aug/2023 | 81 | Sale | 0 |  |
| AURE3 | 23/Feb/2021 | 42 | Purchase | 42 |  |
| AURE3 | 01/Jun/2023 | 45 | Purchase | 87 |  |
| AURE3 | 03/Aug/2023 | 47 | Purchase | 92 | **(134)** |
| AURE3 | 03/Aug/2023 | 42 | Sale | 92 |  |
| AURE3 | 05/Oct/2023 | 48 | Purchase | 95 | **(140)** |
| AURE3 | 05/Oct/2023 | 45 | Sale | 95 |  |
| AURE3 | 03/Nov/2021 | 95 | Sale | 0 |  |

Since the measure accounts for all purchases AND sales occurred on the same day, the 'Shares Balance' column shows the same balance for both rows, but what I really wanted for the purchase transaction row was to get the balance prior to the sale transaction taking place **(numbers in parenthesis)**.

How can I tweak the above DAX code to get that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**1. add [index] column in PowerQuery:**

[image]

**2. calculate measure:**

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE( 
    SUM( fTrans[Shares] ), 
    'fTrans'[Index]<=MAX(fTrans[Index]),
    'fTrans'[Transaction]="Purchase",
    ALLEXCEPT( fTrans, fTrans[Ticker] )
    ) 
- 
CALCULATE( 
    SUM( fTrans[Shares] ), 
    'fTrans'[Index]<=MAX(fTrans[Index]),
    'fTrans'[Transaction]="Sale",
    ALLEXCEPT( fTrans, fTrans[Ticker] )
)
```

**3. calculate column:**

```
Calculate Measure = [Measure]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating calculated columns as the actual dataset contains tens of rows of data so it could potentially slow things down. I got the measure solution for this problem from another forum which I'm posting below.

Comment: Thanks for your share. Got very useful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The following DAX measure code I got from another forum solved this problem for me:

```
Shares balance = 
VAR Shares_Blnc_Tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS( 
        SUMMARIZE( 
            ALL( fTrans ), 
            fTrans[Ticker], 
            fTrans[Date], 
            fTrans[Transaction], 
            fTrans[Shares] 
        ),
        "@Index", 
            SWITCH( 
                TRUE(), 
                fTrans[Transaction] = "Purchase", 1, 
                fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale", 2 
            ), 
        "@Value", 
            SWITCH( 
                TRUE(), 
                fTrans[Transaction] = "Purchase", CALCULATE( SUM( fTrans[Shares] ) ), 
                fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale", - CALCULATE( SUM( fTrans[Shares] ) ) 
            ) 
    )
RETURN
    IF( 
        HASONEVALUE( fTrans[Ticker] ), 
        SUMX( 
            WINDOW( 
                1, 
                ABS, 
                0, 
                REL, 
                Shares_Blnc_Tbl, 
                ORDERBY( fTrans[Date], ASC, [@Index], ASC ), 
                ,
                PARTITIONBY( fTrans[Ticker] ) 
            ), 
            [@Value] 
        ) 
    )
```